# unstack and swap levels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
id   cat  v1  v2
36     A   1   2
36     B   3   4
36     C   5   6
97     A   7   8
97     B   9  10
97     C  11  12
```

I found using `set_index()` and `unstack()` I get

```
df.set_index(['code', 'cat']).unstack()

       v1           v2
code   A   B   C    A    B    C
id
36     1   3   5    2    4    6
97     7   9  11    8   10   12
```

But I want

```
       A            B           C
code   v1    v2     v1    v2    v1    v2
id
36     1     2      3     4     5     6
97     7     8      9     10    11    12
```

How can I get swap the levels in the column axis?

Comment: try `df.set_index(['cat', 'code']).unstack()`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Since you mention [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)

```
df.set_index(['id', 'cat']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[765]: 
cat  A     B       C    
    v1 v2 v1  v2  v1  v2
id                      
36   1  2  3   4   5   6
97   7  8  9  10  11  12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also transpose and unstack specific layers

```
df.set_index(['cat', 'id']).T.stack().unstack(0)

cat  A     B       C    
    v1 v2 v1  v2  v1  v2
id                      
36   1  2  3   4   5   6
97   7  8  9  10  11  12
```